# Is there any way to read the mobile sqlite database in remote?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to read my mobile's Sqlite Date base from remote Access ?? Via network (as like sql Server)

Note :

If I have the SQlite DB File in My Phone. From my computer i need to read / edit the Database.

Comment: I'm not sure you're question is clear enough for anyone to answer.  I suggest you provide more detail to avoid your question being closed.

Comment: Karthick I wonder what led you copy whole db from user's device inspite you can post all the data from app's db in XML to your server

Answer (score 4):

For access over the network, you can use ADB via WiFi with e.g. [adbWireless](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adbwireless-%28widget-version%29/siir.es.adbWireless). Connect to your phones IP

```
adb connect 192.168.100.20
```

Pull your database file via adb.

```
adb pull /data/data/APPLICATION/databases/APPLICATION C:\myProject\APPLICATION.db
```

Then use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) to edit your DB. Then push again.

```
adb push C:\myProject\APPLICATION.db /data/data/APPLICATION/databases/APPLICATION
```

Hope that helps. If you were looking for something else, please clarify your question :)

Comment: is it support only root devices? `adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/user/0/prescinto.mobile/database/cormatrix_db': Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Try this app: SQLiteWeb (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.cm.sqliteweb). It provides remote access to your database without pulling it out.

Pro version includes root access and if you are developing an application, it has the possibility to implement a Content Provider to connect using SQLiteWeb

Yet simple but really usefull!

Answer (score 0):

via adb shell you can log into emulator and read the db for the application. But on the device you can not do that unless device is rooted due to security implications. What exactly you are trying to achieve, are you trying to read some other app's sqlite DB or you are trying to debug your application. If it is the former case then well it is not advisable and if it the later case then you can run your app on the emulator and inspect your sqlite db using adb shell.